# Why am I unable to connect to my ssh server from android?

Tags: server, ssh

I recently set up an ssh server on a 12 year old pc and it's doing a pretty good job when connecting to it from juicessh android ssh client. That is until you decide to connect through cellular data
and the client just gets stuck on connecting and eventually I get connection timed out. This never happened while connected to my home network which is why it suprises me so much. When connecting through other wifi networks such as public transport wifi I get a connection refused error.

Answer (score 1):

Don’t forget to set up forwarding your server's port so it is available to requests from outside your LAN.

Comment: I will look it up and see what I can do. Last week of school before summerbreak for me and on wednesday when I get home I will try to fix it